# NDB StructuredProperty query unexpected result

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have this model:

```
class State(ndb.Model):
  code = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  city_list = ndb.StructuredProperty(City, repeated=True)
  country = ndb.KeyProperty(required=True)

class City(ndb.Model):
  code = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

I implemented this query:

```
 stateData = State.query( State.city_list.name == 'xyz', State.name=='Punjab' ).fetch()
```

I want to implement query on `State` where name is `Punjab`. But `Punjab` has many cities, so I filtered by city name `xyz`.

I'm expecting only the `xyz` city but I'm getting all the cities in the result.

How can I get just the `xyz` city in the result?

Answer (score 3):

You're querying for `State` kinds, so results will be `State` entities, with their *complete* `city_list` property - you can't get just a subset of the `city_list`. So what you're getting is expected.

You could maybe do a projection query, in which case you'd get a list of `State` entities, each with just a single city in `city_list`, see [Projections and multiple-valued properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/projectionqueries#Python_Projections_and_multiple_valued_properties). Watch out for the [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/projectionqueries#Python_Limitations_on_projections).

Or you could redesign your models, maybe with separate `City` entities you can query for directly (instead of structured properties inside the `State` entity).

Answer (score 0):

you should filter before you fetch. the below syntax is based on an older version of ndb where you use Key property

```
class State(ndb.Model):
  code = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  city_list = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=City, repeated=True)
  country = ndb.KeyProperty(required=True)

stateq = State.query( State.name=='Punjab' )
city=stateq.filter(State.City==citykey)
result=city.fetch()
```

I did not try but it will probably work for structured property as well.